# SwiftUI NavigationLink highlight staying highlighted after returning to previous view

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a series of views in SwiftUI.  One is a "Menu View" which consists of a **List** of **NavigationLinks** wrapped in a **NavigationView.**

The code is as follows.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: History(), isActive: $isHistoryViewActive) {
                    Image(systemName: "clock")                        
                    Text("History")                    
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Settings(), isActive: $isSettingsActive) {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                        Text("Settings")
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                    Button(action: {
                        ...
                    }) {
                        Text("My Button")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

The **Settings** view is as follows

```
var body: some View {
     List {
        ...
        Section(header: "Background Music") {
           Toggle("Play", isOn: $isBackGroundMusicOn)
        }
           
        Section(header: "Voice Setting") {
           HStack {
              NavigationLink(destination: VoiceList() {
                 Text(self.voiceNames[self.selectedVoice])
           }
        }
     }
}
```

And lastly, the **VoiceList** view is as follows:

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< VoiceList.voiceNames.count) {voiceIndex in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        voiceChanged(selectedVoice: voiceIndex)
                    }){
                        Text(VoiceList.voiceNames[voiceIndex])
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .isHidden(hidden: voiceIndex != selectedVoice)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when the app returns from the **VoiceList** view to the **Settings** view, the **NavigationLink** remains highlighted, as if it is still active, as shown in the attached screenshot.  I honestly have no idea what may be causing this.  Any ideas or insights are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `onReceive` action on the `List`:

```
List {
    …
}.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITableView.selectionDidChangeNotification)) {
    guard let tableView = $0.object as? UITableView,
          let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRow, animated: true)
}
```

This will deselect the selected row.

Credit for the initial idea for this workaround goes to Pivaisan (from this [Apple Developer thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675098)).

Comment: This is the only solution I could find that worked for me in Xcode 12.5

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem working with List, to solve this i use: `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none`, but as you can expected you will not have the selection aspect, so the right way is try to store the state of selection and clean before leave the screen but in my trys i have no idea how to do that.

Example:

```
struct YourApp: App {
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  Where exactly did you place this line of code?

Comment: In my @main app class i created a init() with this code.
I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The background to your case is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  I don't actually have a @main app class in my app.  I wonder if this could be placed alternatively in the SceneDelegate or HostingController.  Otherwise, I will look into creating an app class.

Comment: you can put it in your appDelegate too, don't need to create a new project, if you are using uikit life cycle.

Comment: I've tried that and still cannot get it work right.  I'll keep tinkering.  Thanks again!

Comment: I also would have thought putting UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none in the init() of my View struct would have done the trick, but nope.